# Converting MIPS assembly into RISCV assembly

Tags: compiler-construction, mips, interpreter, yacc, riscv

I'm working on translating simple MIPS assembly programs written for the QTSPIM simulator into RISCV assembly for didactical scope. My idea is to modify the lexer and parser yacc provided by the open-source project QTSPIM.

This should be the flow:

1. The lexer analyzes the input MIPS assembly and it creates the tokens (e.g., add, load, store..)
2. A modified version of the QTSPIM parser yacc read a token and produces the related RISCV assembly as output.

Would this idea be correct? Or would be better approach the problem in another way?

Answer (score 1):

That should work, I would think.

Here are some other ideas:

- use a script (like sed or awk, or other).
- I've written a simple assembler/disassembler in Excel using formulas and lookup tables.

In any case, you'll need to map registers.

- MIPS has 10 temporaries, whereas RISC V only 7,
- MIPS has 4 argument registers whereas RISC V has 8
- MIPS uses separate return value and argument registers whereas RISC V uses shared return and argument registers.
- MIPS has 8 saved registers, whereas RISC V has 12

If there's parameter passing, it might require more rework especially if you want to follow the RISC V calling convention.

Comment: Thank you for the comment! I prefer to modify the parser mostly for the differences between MIPS and RISCV that you highlighted...